# Exceptions in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I wanted to remove **.html** from pages that I could open in lightbox (triggered by pressing an icon) for esthetic purposes.

**I used following code:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Problem:** It also removes it from VERY important files - for example I wasn't able to go to wp-admin because I think it's called with www.site.com/wp-admin/.html and it shows **403 Forbidden**.

How to resolved this?

Comment: `www.site.com/wp-admin/.html` doesn't look like a valid URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to avoid `wp-admin` directory, you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [L,R=301]
```